# Why are the divs bigger then the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code has the following problems:

1. **Why do the `div`'s `left_right_wrapper` and the `left_column` and the `right_column` flow out of the content_wrapper div?** They should fit in the content_wrapper, and the left_right_wrapper respectively.

   2. I want the html element to not have a scroll bar even when the overflow is set to auto; that is **I need it to be exactly the size of the browser's height** (and not more than it). How can I do that?

*I searched and found that the `JS` function `height()` can return the `height` of the browser screen, but how can I set the value of the height property in `CSS` equal to what is returned by a function in `JS`?*

**Please suggest a fix.**

[Here is the link to the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/2zj8M/1/)

```
<html id="html" style="
      background: url(http://wallpaperscraft.com/image/50510/2560x1024.jpg?orig=1) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: auto;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      padding-top: 68px;
      padding-left: 130px;
      padding-right: 130px;
      height:1024px;
      ">

    <div id="content_wrapper" style="
         height: 83vh;
         overflow: visible;
         background-color: #FAFAFF;
         padding-left: 30px;
         padding-right: 30px;
         //border-style: solid;
         //border-width: 20px;
         //border-color: pink;
         ">

        <div id="information_bar" style="
             /*background-color:buttonface;*/ 
             border-bottom-style:solid; 
             border-bottom-color:#A9A9B1; 
             border-bottom-width:1px; 
             padding:10px;
             ">
            <p style="
               font-family:sans-serif;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 12px;
               color:#00005C; 
               "> I am the information bar </p>
        </div>

        <div id="right_left_wrapper" style="

             position: relative;
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
             overflow: hidden;
             background-color: pink;
             //border-style: solid;
             //border-width: 20px;
             //border-color: red;
             ">
            <div id="left_column" style="
                 //z-index: -5;
                 height:100%; 
                 width: 49.9%; 
                 float:left; 
                 overflow: auto; 
                 border-right-color:grey; 
                 border-right-width: 1px; 
                 border-right-style: solid; 
                 padding-bottom: 20px;
                 padding-left: 20px;
                 padding-right: 20px;
                 padding-top: 10px;
                 background-color: blueviolet;
                ">

                <p id="reading_passage" style="
                   font-family: sans-serif;
                   font-size: 14px;
                   text-align: justify;
                   ">Lorem Ipsum
                     is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
                     not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                     the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
                     software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                     industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                     type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                     typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 
                     Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem 
                     Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
                     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
                     only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 
                     1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                     like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum
                     is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
                     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived 
                     not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                     the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
                     software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                     industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
                     type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                     typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem 
                     Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem 
                     Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
                     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
                     only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 
                     1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                     like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="right_column" style="
                 //z-index:-5;
                 height:100%; 
                 width:50%; 
                 float: right; 
                 overflow: auto;
                 //background-color: brown;
                 padding-bottom: 20px;
                 padding-left: 20px;
                 padding-right: 20px;
                 padding-top: 10px;

                 font-size:14px;
                 font-family: sans-serif;
                ">



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

---

[image]

Comment: where are your <head> and <body> tags ?

Comment: Why are you not using a stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `#right_left_wrapper` has `height:100%` but your `#information_bar` doesn't have any height. Put  `#right_left_wrapper{height:80%;} #information_bar{height:10%}`.

Comment: Setting the height to 77% apparently fixes it but actually it does not, the problem persists when I resize the window (make it smaller vertically) :s

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code to set your html object height (like #html height) equal screen height , this code resize height when resize browser by resize trigger  ...

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

           var theWindow = $(window);
           var mydiv= $("#html");//select your html dom object for set height to 100%

            function resizeBg() {
                mydiv.css("height",window.innerHeight);
            }

            theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

        });
```

you need add a link to jquery library in your head tag then add this code ina script tag under it like this :

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
//your js or jquery code ...
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for the reply. Secondly here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/2zj8M/4/) You can see that there is still a scrollbar with the entire html page, which means the html is bigger than the browser window in height. Secondly, you can see the effects of resizing in the screenshot I am adding the question :s

Comment: Dear @Zarah u can see sample result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Vvf/)
jsfiddle auto add jquery library with left menu option u need only add your js or jquery code in to js code place ...
and , i'm sorry for my mistake in src of jquery cdn that haven't http: and i re edit it in my answer ... !!!